# DJANGO: Showing many-to-many additional fields in template

Tags: django, templates, model, many-to-many, relationship

I have the following situation: A project can belong to multiple departments, Employees are assigned roles to multiple projects. How do I show the roles field in a template? employees.role shows blank...

MODELS

```
class Projects(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Department(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class Employees(models.Model):
    fname = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Departmentprojects(models.Model):
    department = models.ForeignKey(Department)
    projects = models.ForeignKey(Projects)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Employee, through='Membership')

class Membership(models.Model):
    departmentprojects = models.ForeignKey(Departmentprojects)
    employee = models.ForeignKey(Employee)
    role = models.CharField(max_length=20) #i want to show this field in a template
```

VIEW

```
def department_detail(request, company_id):
department = get_object_or_404(Department, pk=department_id)
return render_to_response('test/detail.html', {'department': department})
```

TEMPLATE

```
<h1>{{ department.name }}</h1>

{% for projects in department.departmentprojects_set.all %}
    <h2>{{ projects.projects }}</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for employees in projects.members.all %}
                <li>{{ employee }} | {{ employee.role }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: You have `employees` in one place in the template, and `employee` in another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Iterate over the "through" model instead of the target model:

```
{% for membership in projects.membership_set.all %}
<li>
   {{ membership.employee }} | {{ membership.role }}
</li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: I resolved this by using {% for employees in projects.membership_set.all %} instead of using {% for employees in projects.members.all %}. Not sure what the difference is but it worked!